# Joint PMF of two independent random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. Each of them has a
>   geometric distribution with $E[X] = 2$ and $E[Y] = 3$.
>
> (a) Find the joint p.m.f. of $X$ and $Y$.
>
> (b) Compute the probability that $X + Y \le 4$.
>
> (c) Deﬁne two new random variables by $W = \min{ \left( X, Y \right ) }$ and $Z = \max{ \left( X, Y \right ) }$.
>   Find the joint p.m.f. of $W$ and $Z$.

## Ans:

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. Each of them has a geometric distribution with $E[X] = 2$ and $E[Y] = 3$.

So joint p.m.f. of $X$ and $Y$,

$E[XY] = E[X] E[Y] = 2 * 3 = 6$

Is this correct?

And for $(b)$ and $(c)$ can anyone suggest how to proceed??

for (c), s min(X; Y ) is a geometric random variable with parameter 1 - (1 - p)^2 = 2p - p^2

Comment: Sorry but do you know what is a PMF?

Comment: Probability mass function

Comment: Then why none appear in your question? In particular the passage "So joint p.m.f. of X and Y, E[XY ] = E[X] E[Y ] = 2 *3 = 6 Is this correct?" seems quite misleading.

Comment: @Did can you help correcting me.

Comment: Sure, if you tell us what is a probability mass function...

Comment: @Did The probability mass function, P(X = x) = f(x), of a discrete random variable X is a function that satisfies the following properties:
(1) P(X = x) = f(x) > 0  if x ∈ the support S
(2)  ∑x∈Sf(x)=1
(3) P(X∈A)=∑x∈Af(x)

Comment: And when they say that X has a geometric distribution with E[X]=2 this means that P(X=x) is what?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The pmf for geometric distribution (the probability that it will take $k$ trials to get the first success) is given by
$$\Pr(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1}\,p\,$$
where $p$  is the success probability in each trial.

It is also known that the mean of $X$ is $\mathrm{E}(X) = \frac{1}{p}$.

Can you get it from here?

Comment: Thanks for (a) So u suggest pmf is E(X) = 2 ???... Any help on (b) and (c), can you help?

Comment: @nini no way. I didn't suggest that. pmf is a function of trials ($k$) and you say it is a constant.

Comment: Its given in the question that E(X) is = 2. And as per your comment, pmf = (1/2)[(1/2)^(k-1)] , correct?

Comment: @nini so then you almost got (a). Just remember that they _are independet_

Comment: almost? is nt that correct? and for b also, i have some hint, i can do... For (c) i have found the min, can anyone help with the option c

Comment: @nini for (c) you have to remember that $p$ is different $1/2$ and $1/3$ (do you see the product sign over there where you have found that formula?): $p = 1-\prod_m(1-p_{m})$. In your case $p_1=1/2$ and $p_2=1/3$ so $p=2/3$.

Comment: your formula is from wiki, right? anyway what is for max?? any idea?

Comment: @nini guess [this](http://mathoverflow.net/a/41614/40474) can be helpful.

Comment: so the max(X, Y)  is  log n + lambda .... I did not get exactly..like max(X,Y) what this should be?

Comment: I got this from somewhere that, if X and Y be independent geometric random variables, where X has parameter p
and Y has parameter q.E[max(X, Y )] = E[X] +E[Y ] − E[min(X, Y )]. From below, in part (c), we know that min(X, Y ) is a geometric random variable mean p + q − pq. Therefore, E[min(X, Y )] = 1
p+q−pq
, and we get
E[max(X, Y )] = 1/p+1/q−1/(p + q − pq)
.

Comment: @André Nicolas Can you check this please

Answer (score -2):

$P=1/E[X]=0.5$

$P=1/E[y]=0.333$

$PX(x)=(1-0.5)^{k-1}0.5$

$PY(y)=(1-0.33)^{k-1}0.333$

The Joint Probability:

$E[XY]=E[X]*E[y]=2\cdot3=6$

$p=1/E[XY]=0.167$
$PX,Y(x,y)=(1-0.167)^{k-1}0.167 ~~~  K=1,2,3.......$